# What does the digit 2 in this grep commandline mean?

Tags: grep

```
grep -2riP
```

I saw it on commandline fu. I checked the man page, but could not find it, it is possible that I may have missed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the grep man-page:

> -C NUM, **-NUM**, --context=NUM
>                 Print NUM lines of output context.  Places a line containing a group separator (described under --group-separator)
>   between contiguous groups
>                 of matches.  With the -o or --only-matching option, this has no effect and a warning is given.

so, `grep -2` is equivalent to `grep -C 2`, which tells grep to display 2 lines before and after a match.